# Text box not remembering values jQuery cookie

Tags: jquery, html

I have a text box in my JSP page. I used jQuery cookie to remember the previously entered value after page refresh(done by submit button). I have the following but it is not working. Where am I going wrong?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       var prev = $(".companyname").val();
      $("input.check").val($.cookie("companyname",prev));
 });
```

And these are my elements

```
    <input type="text" name = "companyname" class = "companyname"> <br/>
    <input type="Submit" value = " Submit " onClick = " javascript:window.location.reload(); ">
```

Comment: is .company is the name of the cookie ?
Because cookie accepts name and value.

Example to save = $.cookie("name", value);

Comment: cpmpanyname is the class name of my textbox.

Comment: What is the name of cookie ? you have to retrieve value with the name of cookie..
Example 

$.cookie("visits", 10);
console.log($.cookie("visits")); // print "10"

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/8aU7r/3/ . Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store input-element's value into cookie whether in client-side (javascript) or server-side.
Here is an example:

```
<input type="text" name="companyname" class="companyname">
<input type="button" value=" Submit " id="submit">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".companyname").val($.cookie("companyname")||'');
  $('#submit').click(function(){
     var value = $('.companyname').val();
    $.cookie('companyname', value);
    window.location.reload();
  });
});
</script>
```

I also suggest to name cookies using non-special characters and white-spaces.
So $.cookie("companyname") make more sense.

Comment: didnt work. Text box is blank after clicking submit.